# How to ensure natural ventilation through a shaft?

Tags: civil-engineering, building-physics

I have a small shaft, 2.5m wide by 4m deep, sunk into the ground. Due to explosion protection I should ensure "natural ventilation" - this is the termgiven in the relevant ordinance, no air flow specified. As the shaft is sunk into the ground, in the summer months it will always be colder than the air above. I see no way to ensure passive ventilation, so I will need a small blower.

Or am I wrong and there is way to ensure natural ventilation?

Comment: Would a small blower even satisfy the need for "natural ventilation"? My interpretation of "natural" is by definition passive.

Comment: Well, with sufficient technical ventilation you don't need declare an Ex-Zone either. Should also mention that the gas in question is methane, lighter than air, so an opening at the top could suffice.

Comment: You won't get any ventilation in a shaft like that unless there is some way for the air to flow *in* as well as *out*. Methane is less dense than air (molecular weight 16 compared with 28 for N2 and 32 for O2) so for passive natural ventilation, maybe all you need is a separate pipe from the outside to the *bottom* of the shaft, to let unpolluted air in to replace the methane as it rises.

Comment: @alephzero that was my first idea, but I had doubts that without thermal convection I get significant air change. Totes forgot about density.